Formula to multiply a value by a factor that is based on the word found in another column
I would like a Google Sheets formula in column C that checks what word is in column A and then multiplies the value in column B by a factor selected based on the matched word.
For example, if the matched word is:

Cars, then factor is 1;
Trucks, then factor is 2;
Bikes, then factor is 3





A
B
C




1
Type
Amount
Desired Result


2
Trucks
0.4
0.8


3
Cars
0.3
0.3


4
Trucks
0.7
1.4


5
Bikes
0.5
1.5




There are different approaches depending on the number of words you expect to have:
MATCH
This will return a factor incrementing by 1 depending on the position of the word in a hardcoded list or E2:E4:
Single Row Versions
------------------------    
=IFNA(B2 * MATCH(A2, {"Cars"; "Trucks"; "Bikes"}, 0)))

=IFNA(B2 * MATCH(A2, $E$2:$E$4, 0)))   # range ref. for words

Array Versions
-----------------
=INDEX(IFNA(B2:B * MATCH(A2:A, {"Cars"; "Trucks"; "Bikes"}, 0)))

=INDEX(IFNA(B2:B * MATCH(A2:A, $E$2:$E$4, 0)))   # range ref. for words

VLOOKUP
Use a lookup table of hardcoded column pairs with words in one column and factors in the other or a range reference to words E2:E4 and factors in F2:F4:
Single Row Versions
------------------------    
=IFNA(B2 * VLOOKUP(A2, {"Cars", 1; "Trucks", 2; "Bikes", 3}, 2, 0))

=IFNA(B2 * VLOOKUP(A2, $E$2:$F$4, 2, 0))   # range ref. for words

Array Versions
-----------------
=INDEX(IFNA(B2:B * VLOOKUP(A2:A, {"Cars", 1; "Trucks", 2; "Bikes", 3}, 2, 0)))

=INDEX(IFNA(B2:B * VLOOKUP(A2:A, $E$2:$F$4, 2, 0)))   # range ref. for words

